# How to insert data instance from view in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem to insert instance data in django, this is my model

```
class DipPegawai(models.Model):
    PegID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    PegNamaLengkap = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    PegUser = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

class DipHonorKegiatanPeg(models.Model):
    KegID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    PegID = models.ForeignKey(DipPegawai)
```

this is my view

```
def tambah_klaimhonor(request):
    klaim = {}
    user = request.user.id
    pegid = DipPegawai.objects.filter(PegUser = user).values_list('PegID',flat=True)[0]
    honoruser = DipHonorKegiatanPeg(PegID=pegid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = KlaimHonorGuruKarForm(request.POST, instance=pegid)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index_klaimhonor')
    klaim['form'] = KlaimHonorGuruKarForm()
    return redirect('index_klaimhonor')
```

when i insert data, i get this error

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /kegiatan/tambah_klaimhonor
Exception Value: Cannot assign "41L": "DipHonorKegiatanPeg.PegID" must be a "DipPegawai" instance.
```

my form

```
class KlaimHonorGuruKarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DipHonorKegiatanPeg
        fields = ('KegNama', 'KegTglMulai', 'KegJamMulai', 'KegTglAkhir', 'KegJamAkhir',)
        labels = {'KegNama': 'Nama Kegiatan', 'KegTglMulai': 'Mulai Tanggal Kegiatan',
                  'KegJamMulai': 'Mulai Jam Kegiatan',
                  'KegTglAkhir': 'Akhir Tanggal Kegiatan', 'KegJamAkhir': 'Akhir Jam Kegiatan'}
        widgets = {
            # 'KegNama': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'KegJamAkhir': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'KegTglMulai': DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker', 'data-date-format': 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'required': True}),
            'KegTglAkhir': DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker1', 'data-date-format': 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'required': True}),
            'KegJamMulai': TextInput(attrs={'id': 'timepicker2', 'required': True}),
        }
```

I'm using user login for inserting data in DipHonorKegiatanPeg, but i want to insert PegID.DipHonorKegiatanPeg instance from DipPegawai?

Comment: Can you reduce to a [mcve] ?

Comment: i'v reduce it @xiawi

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is focused on `honoruser = DipHonorKegiatanPeg(DipPegawai)`, I think you not fully understand how `class` *object* is work.

If you try with `DipHonorKegiatanPeg(DipPegawai)` that mean the class of `DipHonorKegiatanPeg` is instanced from ***original*** class `DipPegawai` model.

You should change it to class instance, eg:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def tambah_klaimhonor(request, id):
    ....
    honoruser = get_object_or_404(DipHonorKegiatanPeg, PegID__PegID=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = KlaimHonorGuruKarForm(request.POST, instance=honoruser)
```

> **Note:** the `id/pk` is automatically generated by django as primary key with `AutoField`.

---

***Update***;

```
# KegID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) => return a `number`.
# PegID = models.ForeignKey(DipPegawai) => return `ForeignKey` class instance.

from django.shortcuts import (render, get_object_or_404)
# ...

def tambah_klaimhonor(request):
    pegawai = get_object_or_404(DipPegawai, PegUser=request.user) 
    # or
    # pegawai, truefalse = DipPegawai.objects.get_or_create(PegUser=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = KlaimHonorGuruKarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            initial = form.save(commit=False)
            initial.PegID = pegawai
            initial.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect('index_klaimhonor')
    else:
        form = KlaimHonorGuruKarForm()
    return render(request, 'templatename.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: change `honoruser = DipHonorKegiatanPeg(PegID=pegid)` to `honoruser = DipHonorKegiatanPeg(PegID__PegID=pegid)`

Comment: what output of of `pegid`? is that a number or what?

Comment: it is a number (integer)

Comment: i get this error 
`  

'PegID__PegID' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: let me see your `KlaimHonorGuruKarForm`

Comment: i've inserted to my question

Comment: if using `get_object_or_404`, i get page not found

Comment: it because`DipPegawai` or  `DipHonorKegiatanPeg` object doesn't created yet.

Comment: i've created it @sanca-kembang, i think if using get_object_or_404, we must use 2 parameter in function right like `def function(request,id)`? but i don't need id, just take from it 
`user = request.user.id
    pegid = DipPegawai.objects.filter(PegUser = user).values_list('PegID',flat=True)[0]`

Comment: still the same problem, if using get_object_or_404

Comment: I just think you not created yet an object for `DipPegawai`, that why you got an 404 error...